# My model fit too slow, tringle of val_loss is 90

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a task to write a neural network. On input of 9 neurons, and output of 4 neurons for a multiclass classification problem. I have tried different models and for all of them:

- Drop-out mechanism is used.
- Batch normalization is used.

And the resulting neural networks all are overfitting. Precision is <80%, I want to have min 90% precision. Loss is 0.8 on the median.

Please, can you suggest to me what model I should use?

Dataset:

- [TMS_coefficients.RData file](https://rdrr.io/github/fernandoPalluzzi/tmsClassifier/man/tms.coef.html#heading-1)

Part of my code:

```
(trainX, testX, trainY, testY) = train_test_split(dataset,
    values, test_size=0.25, random_state=42)

# модель нейронки
visible = layers.Input(shape=(9,))
hidden0 = layers.Dense(64, activation="tanh")(visible)
batch0 = layers.BatchNormalization()(hidden0)
drop0 = layers.Dropout(0.3)(batch0)
hidden1 = layers.Dense(32, activation="tanh")(drop0)
batch1 = layers.BatchNormalization()(hidden1)
drop1 = layers.Dropout(0.2)(batch1)
hidden2 = layers.Dense(128, activation="tanh")(drop1)
batch2 = layers.BatchNormalization()(hidden2)
drop2 = layers.Dropout(0.5)(batch2)
hidden3 = layers.Dense(64, activation="tanh")(drop2)
batch3 = layers.BatchNormalization()(hidden3)
output = layers.Dense(4, activation="softmax")(batch3)
model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=visible, outputs=output)

model.compile(optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(0.0001),
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['Precision'],)

history = model.fit(trainX, trainY, validation_data=(testX, testY), epochs=5000, batch_size=256)
```

[image: Graph of loss. Now i have dropout and batch, and neural network and fitting have result after 75% loss]

Comment: "..Precision is <80%", can you elaborate? You can't decide on overfitting with a single precision value. You need precision/recall/accuracy whatever both for train and test data. Please add some fitting curve plots demonstrating both train and test losses. Also, show your code.

Answer (score 2):

From the loss curve, I can say it is not overfitting at all! In fact, your model is underfitting. Why? because, when you have stopped training, the loss curve for the validation set has not become flat yet. That means, your model still has the potential to do well if it was trained more.

The model overfits when the training loss is decreasing (or remains the same) but the validation loss gradually increases without decreasing. This is clearly not the case

So, what you can do:

- Try training longer.
- Add more layers.
- Try different activation functions like `ReLU` instead of `tanh`.
- Use lower dropout (probably your model is struggling to learn for high value of dropouts).
- Make sure you have shuffled your data before train-test splitting (if you are using `sklearn` for `train_test_split()` then it is done by default) and also check if the test data is similar to the train data and both of them goes under the same preprocessing steps.

Comment: i think more layers not resolve my problem. I have only 650 size of dataset, this is very small count,

Comment: and i train 1000000 epochs, but result not up

Comment: after 20000 epochs validation loss 1.2, test - 0.2. obviously, problem - overfitting